# Why newly created entity object with navigation property is automaticly added to ObjectContext?

Tags: entity-framework

I have to entities: Company and Location (one to many). When I create new Location entity object and assign navigation property(Company) with the navigation property of already existing Location object (`Location _new = new Location(); _new.Company = _old.Company`). It seems that at that point newly created object is added to Object Context automatically, because when I call SaveChanges method that object is insert to database although I didn't call ObjectContext.AddObject(_new). I'm new in EF so there is probably reason why I have result like this? Is there need to assign also CompanyReference filed too and how to do it in order to block this behavior? I want explicitly to add new object myself.

> `IDaoFactory daoFactory = new DaoFactory();
>
>   ILocationDao locaitonDao = daoFactory.GetLocationDao();
>
>   IEnumerable<Location> locations = locaitonDao.GetLocations();
>
>   Location _old = locations.First();
>
>   Location _new = new Location();
>
>   _new.LocationName = _old.LocationName;
>
>   _new.Company = _old.Company;// 1
>
>   _new.Address = _old.Address;
>
>    //...
>
>    ContactEntities.SaveChanges();//2`
>
> If I execute line (1) instantly _new object is added to object context and I can see additional datarow in my datagrid after line (2) is executed.

Answer (score 0):

That's OK. 
"Clever" Entity Framework founds out that you have attached a new object to an object already available in ObjectStateManager and adds the newly attached object to it with the Added state, so it is added on the SaveChanges() call.

Comment: But as said I don't want that. I added new property to Locaiton entity called RelatedCompany to keep reference to specific Company until I decide to save object when I'm going to assign this to navigation property. It works, but I don't know how good is that?